# My cat got into a fight with an owl. Should I be worried?

Tags: cats, injury

A few weeks ago my cat (just barely not a kitten anymore) got into a fight with a small forest Owl. The owl didn't survive this. The cat has not been acting strange since and I noticed no injuries so far.

Should I be worried? Could there be internal injuries that only show later?

Comment: Has the cat had it's rabies vaccine?

Comment: @JamesJenkins Yes

Comment: Since that was a few weeks ago and your cat is not showing any signs of injury I'd really doubt there's anything to be worried about. A cat would display this in a matter of days.

Comment: @D.Tanya can you expand this into an answer?

Comment: I'm no veterinarian, but I do treat [some apes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human) from time to time, and I'd feel fairly confident in saying that if it's been a few weeks and you've observed no change, the only things that could have happened are infection with some strange disease which has an asymtomatic incubation period of that long -- of which there are _very_ few -- or some sort of minor internal damage that won't heal, but isn't causing any harm, either.

Comment: Depends. I recommend calling your veterinarian to enquire about this situation. You never know. There may be some precautionary steps you could take to prevent future injury or illness. Hope all goes well.

Comment: @Zaralynda Sorry, I can't expand it into an answer as there's nothing to add to it. I think it can still pass off as a comment.

Answer (score 1):

There could be internal injuries which would need a vets diagnosis to determine.  A simple check you could do for skelatel or muscle injuries in to pet your cat all over. Not roughly but enough you can her parts underneath. And if she shows discomfort at any particular spot or spots might give you indication. But acting strangely is a vague distribution. I would take my car to the vet. Best of luck though.